# Mongoose Model Save Error E11000

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schema:

```
var loftSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name        : { type: String, trim: true, required: true },
    location    : { type: { type: String, enum: 'Point', default: 'Point'}, coordinates: { type:      [Number], default: [0,0] } },
    radius      : { type: Number, required: true },
    private     : { type: Boolean, required: true },
    created     : { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    updated     : { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    members     : [{ type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Users'}],
    posts       : [{ type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Posts'}]
});
```

Note that both members and posts are references to other Mongoose Schemas.
Below is the function I use to create a `Loft` object.

```
function createLoft(req, res) {
    var params = req.body;
    var deferred = q.defer();

    var form = new multiparty.Form();
    var image, lat, lon, name, radius, private, path, creatorID;

    form.on('file', function(name, file){
        path = file.path;
    });

    // listen on field event for title
    form.on('field', function(key, value){
        if(key == "lat"){
            lat = value;
        }else if(key == "lon"){
            lon = value;
        }else if(key == "name"){
            name = value;
        }else if(key == "radius"){
            radius = value;
        }else if(key == "creator_id"){
            creatorID = value;
        }else if(key == "private"){
            private = value;
        }else return;
    });

    // listen on part event for image file
    form.on('part', function(part){
         if (!part.filename) return;
         if (part.name !== 'image') return part.resume();
         image = {};
         image.filename = part.filename;
         image.size = 0;
         part.on('data', function(buf){
           image.size += buf.length;
         });
    });

    form.on('close', function(){
        var response = { "status": 200, "created": null };
        var created = new Loft({
            name: name,
            location: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [lat, lon] },
            radius: radius,
             private:private
        });
        response.created = created;
        created.members = [creatorID];
        created.attach('image', {'path': path}, function(err){
            if(err){
                response.status = 500;
                response.created = err;
                 deferred.resolve(response);
                 return;
            }else {
                response.created = created;
                created.save(function (err, object) {
                    if (err) {
                        response.status = 400;
                        response.created = err;
                    }
                    deferred.resolve(response);
                });
             }
         });   
    });
    // parse the form
    form.parse(req);

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

I do a multipart upload from the client (iOS) and parse the form on the server. Everything works great the first time I create a loft and I'm able to add the corresponding user id as the first member of the group. However, if I try the call a second time, I get this back:

```
{
  "name": "MongoError",
  "code": 11000,
  "err": "insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index:    loft.lofts.$creator_id_1 dup key: { : null }"
}
```

My goal is to be able to create Lofts that are almost exactly identical apart from the generated _id field from MongoDB. Every time I try creating a similar loft, I get that error thrown. Is there anyway to circumvent that? And what does the error even mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the creator_id field of your lofts collection is set to be a unique index. I don't see it on your schema however. I may be missing it or did you perhaps change your schema and used to have it?  The only way to not get this error is to remove that unique index requirement. You may have to reindex mongo using the shell if fixing your code does not prove successful.

Login to your shell in terminal with `mongo` then type `use loft` to switch db. You can view indexes with `db.lofts.getIndexes()` - you will probably see the creator_id field. You can force a reindex with `db.lofts.reIndex()`

You'll want to evaluate your code though as creator_id may need to be a unique field but that is for your to determine based on your needs.

Comment: It was because 1) I didn't have sparse: true set and 2) because I didn't drop the database after changing the schema.